# Within a Journey, insert a record for the Contact into another DataExtension based on a Decision Split

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions

I would like to insert a record for a Contact into another DataExtension based on a Decision Split within a Journey.

I do not see any documentation stating this is possible, and I havent found any articles or questions here on Stack exchange so I thought I would ask.

There is some AmpScript that allows for Upserting a value into a column, but this does not really meet my need.

Is this something doable?

I could accomplish this creating a custom activity, but I am hopeful there is something native to Marketing Cloud that can accomplish it.

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish this..

1. Use Contact Update activity in your Journey to update a specific attribute value for those Contacts you want to have in a new Data Extension.
2. Set up a Filter Activity in Automation Studio to check this Data Extension and filter out the ones with this specific attribute value to your target Data Extension.

The downside is of course that the Automation will only run once in an hour, so it's not real time.

Comment: Good answer, thanks.  Will mark as Accepted after my testing should it accomplish my desired results.